# Maximizing any window leaves a vertical bar uncovered

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

The vertical bar is in the left and it's much wider than and unrelated to the unity side bar. It's as if the desktop area does not include a left vertical bar, but this applies only to maximized windows: unmaximized windows can occupy that area and indeed remain visible (well, those parts thereof that are in that area) when the window is maximized over them. I switched to metacity and I got the same problem. I also restarted unity, without logging out and back in.

I need to know the reason. I know a reboot will fix it.

Comment: A screenshot would probably help us understand what you mean.

Comment: @gronostaj I would need to delete this question but I can't complete the sign up at this time. Can you delete it for me?

Comment: Why do you want to delete it? If you've found the solution, please post it as an answer. Other people facing the same issue may find it. If you really want to delete it, you'll have to flag it for moderator's attention. Regular users can't delete questions.

Comment: @dsstorefile That's why I wanted to delete it. I realized that posting this on unix.stackexchange was a better idea. What is your suggestion? What do you do with "cross-posts" (that one can't delete)? (also @gronostaj)

Answer (score 0):

This line in a script I tested is the culprit: `xprop -id <any window> -f _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL 32c -set _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL '200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0'`. Replacing `200` with `0` solved the problem. (What would be a general way to undo all such `xprop` changes anyway?)

Somebody please explain why it affects all windows even though I used it only for one specific window. Some explanation as to what this line was supposed to do wouldn't be bad. If there is no answer in a while, I'll "accept" mine.